# How to install R libraries after using homebrew?

Tags: r, homebrew

for the first time I'm using `homebrew` and `homebrew cask` to install programmes and manage packages. After `brew install homebrew/science/R` and `brew cask install rstudio`I tried to install some libraries within `rstudio` but always end up with Warnings and errors with similar syntax:

```
installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
Paket ‘Rcpp’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
libs
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/Rcpp’`

Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status`

installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
Paket ‘stringi’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu55/data
checking for R_HOME...  /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources
checking for R... /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
checking for R >= 3.1.0... yes
checking for cat... /bin/cat
/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 150:       make: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 151: make: command not found`
```

and so on...

I installed `Xcode 5.1.1`on my `OSX 10.8.5` (not via Homebrew)
at the beginning of the whole Mac setup process and assumed `Command Line Tools`are included.

By the way, brew doctor says `Your system is ready to brew`

How can I approach that?

Comment: You have Xcode and the command line tools installed? Which OS version are you on?

Comment: There is something you need to do to accept the license or the command line tools won't work. I always forget what exactly and end up googleing it.

Comment: `xcode-select --install` should get you `make` and the other basic necessities.

Comment: @ Roland. I focused on that. At the beginning opened `Xcode` accepted the license

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tried that already in order to download `command line tools`. Always get `code-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'` I'll gave up on that because I assumed `CLT` is a part of `Xcode`by default.

Comment: @Mamba apologies for not seeing you're on 10.8.5. Try https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Installation_on_OS_X_10.8_Mountain_Lion#Install_Xcode to get Xcode installed.

Comment: @ hrbrmstr Thank you so much! Thats it. I will update the question. Or do you want to post a solution to accept?

Answer (score 0):

As said by hrbrmstr in the comments, in OS X 10.8.5, you also have to [install the command line tools](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Installation_on_OS_X_10.8_Mountain_Lion#Install_Xcode):

> Install Command Line Tools (CLT)
>
> After Xcode is installed the compiler and command line tools must be installed. This is performed by starting Xcode, opening preferences, click on Download, then Install for Command Line Tools. The CLT are placed in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer and various system directories.